# Facebook Graph Bad Request

Tags: facebook

I'm using facebook graph api to to get the cover picture of an event.
I'm using this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/134692733275104/events?fields=cover?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/134692733275104/events?fields=cover?access_token=****|****) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

When I use the link without the ?fields=cover part it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the second `?` with a `&` like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/134692733275104/events?fields=cover&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET
```